# java - timer execution

Tags: java, timer

I want to implement a sort of timer in java. 
I exaplain: my code should run for 10 seconds; I have 3 different integers (a, b and c, all of them are initialized to 0) and I want to increase and decrease them in different time intervals:

- From 0 to 3 seconds a = 1, b = 0 and c = 0.
- From 3 to 6 seconds a = 0, b = 1 and c = 0.
- From 6 to 10 seconds a = 0, b = 0 and c = 1.

Here is my code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

a = 1
Thread.sleep(3000);
b = 1; 
a = 0;
Thread.sleep(3000);
b = 0;
c = 1;
```

It works but it's very ugly!! 
How can I improve this code? Should I use a stopwatch? (I read some solutions which use swing timer, I'm not using swing components so I don't need it)

Comment: If the answer has code that works, try asking on Code Review.

Comment: It could be done in different ways, all depends on the context. Where this code will be used? For what?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your method, use System.currentTimeMillis() to get the start time. Then inside your method, use System.currentTimeMillis() to get the current time, and check that current time against the start time to get your elapsed time. Do whatever you want based on the elapsed time.

Edit: Unless you want to schedule something, in which case use the Timer class. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html